# Used .Hide for form and can't find the program in task manager

Tags: delphi

Funny story: I was busy with my PAT and I tried to make a form close itself when I move to another form. Before you tell me that I'm an idiot, I am aware that I am.
I accidentally did this without thinking when I click a button:

```
frmRegistration.Hide;
```

My question is: How can I close it, or what is it called in the task manager?

Comment: The Windows Task Manager doesn't show windows.

Comment: Okay, but is there a way to close the program or do I have to restart my laptop?

Comment: Closing the program is easy: Just locate the program's name (like `contoso.exe`) in the Task Manager and kill the process. Alternatively, in a command prompt, type (`taskkill /im contoso.exe /f`).

Comment: That's the problem, I can't find it anywhere in the task manager. Not in Apps or Background Processes. Oh wait, I didn't read the second sentence, I'll try that.

Comment: If you are using Windows 10, you need to look on the "Details" tab.

Comment: Thank you so much, the command prompt method worked. And I will also remember to look in the details tab next time.

Answer (score -1):

In Task Manager the `.exe` (for all forms) should be called what you named your project file for example: *project_p*. You could maybe use `form.Close` instead of `form.Hide`, though I think both are fine.